# Recovering files from a computer attacked by a malware or virus that encrypts all of my files

Tags: windows-8.1, malware

My computer (running Windows 8.1) was infected by a malware or virus yesterday. Now all of my files are encrypted such as music, videos, documents… Now I want to recover all of my files.

Comment: Unfortunately, recovering malware-encrypted files is one of the few topics not covered in our canonical thread.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your computer was infected with the [Cryptolocker virus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptoLocker), or a variant.

Unfortunately, unless you have a backup of the encrypted files, you are out of luck.  There is no way to recover the files.

Some people have had success paying the ransom, however it is not recommended.as the key they provide doesnt always work.

Comment: Pretty much this.  There are a few versions of Cryptolocker where the master key has been acquired, but if its not one of those, you are probably out of luck.   You might be able to use something like photorec to pull deleted copies of your files (ie old copies) which may not have been hit, but otherwise you have just had it reinforced why you need backups.